# How to get my LogiLink BT0015 Bluetooth-adapter to work with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, bluetooth, wireless-adapter

I have a LogiLink BT0015 USB to Bluetooth adapter that I would like to use on my computer running Windows 10 Pro.

The drivers supplied on a mini-CD in the package are useless.

How can I get it to work?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed. You can also contact the developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: Such adapters don't need anything on Windows 10. You simple plug them into an USB port and that's it. Windows detects it and installs the drivers and then the device is read to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drivers on the CD are totally useless, but generic Windows 10 drivers work just fine.

- When connecting the Bluetooth adapter, three Bluetooth devices are being created:
  Generic Bluetooth Radio, Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator and Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator.
- This is everything you need, except ***there is one more you need to do***.

  Press [Win] -> "Control Panel" -> Hardware and Sound [Add a device]

  [image]
- Here you will find your Bluetooth devices (along with other things).
  Now just choose the device you want to add.

Then you are all done. Everything works just fine for me and right now I listening on my wireless Bluetooth headset with a very good range as a result.

Useful things:
Manage Bluetooth devices ([Win] -> "Bluetooth" -> [Manage Bluetooth devices])
Device Manager ([Win] -> "Device Manager" -> [Bluetooth])

Comment: I'm not getting this to work. As you wrote the installation is effortless, but I can't seem to get any sound out. I'm connecting my Bose QC2 head phones and they show up as "paired" in Manage Bluetooth devices but I don't get any sound. The head phones does not show up in Sound settings, either under Output or Input.

Comment: Scratch that. I managed to connect the head phones, but only after using the Bose Connect app to clear paired devices. After that I could connect and the head phones shows up as "Bose" as well as "LE-Bose". The former works, while the latter does nothing.